# Understanding Gurobi Python as a Beginner

Tags: python, gurobi

I am novice in Gurobi Language. I am trying to solve some LPs and MIPs using GurobiPy, so the approach I thought I would take was to look at some examples how to add constraints and all. But in the examples provided by Gurobi website, the actual documentation on how to add mathematical constraints to the model was like finding a needle in haystack. From my fellow seniors I would like to know how can I approach to learn to add constraints actually. Thank you. I already found some understanding, but there are things like sum( * , 1) etc which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

These tutorials can be a starting point:

https://www.gurobi.com/resource/abremod-getting-started-intro/

To get more help here on StackOverflow, please consider phrasing your question less broad and try to ask a specific question.